# Efficient conversion of nested lists with varying length to a data.frame (with base R)

Tags: r, list-comprehension

I am hoping to get some assistance with converting nested lists into a data frame.  My solution iterates multiple times and I was wondering if there is a more efficient solution.

A toy example of a nested list:

```
nested_list <- list(list('date' = '2018-01-10', 'value1' = 1, 'value2' = 2), 
                    list('date' = '2018-01-09', 'value1' = 3, 'value2' = 4), 
                    list('date' = '2018-01 08', 'value1' = NULL, 'value2' = NULL), 
                    list('date' = '2018-01-07', 'value1' = NULL, 'value2' = NULL), 
                    list('date' = '2018-01-06', 'value1' = 5, 'value2' = 6))
```

As you can see that some values are NULL.  My intention is to omit this data entirely.

Currently, I first mask for all nested lists where length is greater than one.

```
mask <- sapply((lapply(nested_list, unlist)), length) > 1
```

I then apply rbind via do.call  and convert to a data.frame.  At the end of the process I have to coerce numerical values because they are all converted to character strings.

```
data.frame(do.call('rbind', lapply(nested_list[mask], unlist)), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

As you can see this looks messy and I was wondering if there is a more efficient way to accomplish the conversion to a data frame.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a `base R` option where we loop through the elements of 'nested_list' and `if` there is `any` element have a `length` that is 0 then assign it to `NULL` or else return a `data.frame`

```
res <- do.call(rbind, lapply(nested_list, function(x) 
      if(any(lengths(x) == 0)) NULL else data.frame(x, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)))
res
#         date value1 value2
#1 2018-01-10      1      2
#2 2018-01-09      3      4
#3 2018-01-06      5      6
```

In the input dataset, the 'date' values are `character`, it is better to store as `Date` class

```
res$date <- as.Date(res$date)
str(res)
# 'data.frame':   3 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ date  : Date, format: "2018-01-10" "2018-01-09" "2018-01-06"
# $ value1: num  1 3 5
# $ value2: num  2 4 6
```

Comment: Thank you akrun, this looks more elegant than my approach.  I left out the part where I process the dates so as not to clutter the example.  I have accepted the answer but was unable to upvote because of my lowly ranking.

Answer (score 2):

I know your title says "base R", but you also ask for a more efficient way. So as an alternative here is a `tidyverse` solution:

```
nested_list %>%
    map(unlist) %>%
    rbind_all() %>%
    filter(complete.cases(.)) %>%
    mutate_at(vars(contains("value")), as.numeric);
## A tibble: 3 x 3
#  date       value1 value2
#  <chr>       <dbl>  <dbl>
#1 2018-01-10     1.     2.
#2 2018-01-09     3.     4.
#3 2018-01-09     5.     6.
```

---

Or alternatively (thanks to @arun):

```
nested_list %>% 
    transpose %>% 
    map_df(~ .x %>% replace(., lengths(.)==0, NA) %>% unlist) %>% 
    filter(!is.na(value1))
```

Comment: You may need an additional step to convert the 'value' columns to 'numeric' as it is mentioned in the OP's post

Comment: I would think that you can use `transpose` as well `nested_list %>% transpose %>% map_df(~ .x %>% replace(., lengths(.)==0, NA) %>% unlist)  %>% filter(!is.na(value1))` and this would avoid the type conversion :=)

Comment: @akrun Thanks & updated. I hope you don't mind that I've also included your solution.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help.  That looks like a good solution but I am trying to avoid package dependencies (outside of httr) in this case.  I tried to upvote but was unable to.

Comment: @user9630195 You’re very welcome, and the important thing is that you got the solution you were looking. That’s the beauty of R: there’s always more than one solution;-)

Comment: Not at all.   Glad that you find it useful

Answer (score 2):

Another solution:

```
> data.table::rbindlist(nested_list[sapply(nested_list, function(x) min(lengths(x))) > 0])
         date value1 value2
1: 2018-01-10      1      2
2: 2018-01-09      3      4
3: 2018-01-06      5      6
```

Comment: Thanks very much.  Unfortunately I am not using data.table package.  Its definitely on my list of things to learn.  I tried to upvote but was unable to because I am new to this forum and my reputation is ranked too low (interesting feature).